# Xcode deployment info Mac is off?

Tags: xcode

I have SwiftUI project , and i can't turn on Deployment for Mac .

the option already OFF , i am not sure why ?

Xcode version 12.5
macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

[image]

is it because not supporting SwiftUI!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `iPad` box in order to enable the `Mac` one.